# Type expression is ambiguous without more context in `possibleCloseGestureModes |= .TapNavigationBar`

Tags: swift2

```
if gestureRecognizer.isKindOfClass(UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
    if self.isPointContainedWithinNavigationRect(point) {         
        possibleCloseGestureModes |= .TapNavigationBar 
    } 
    if self.isPointContainedWithinCenterViewContentRect(point) {
       possibleCloseGestureModes |= .TapCenterView 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is `|=` a custom operator defined in your codebase?

Comment: No, it was previously used in my project but after migrating to swift 2.0 it gives an error.

Comment: What I wanted to know is *how is this operator defined*? Please show the code where `|=` is declared so that we know what it does (I've got an idea but I want to verify first).